# Hadoop on Windows - "Error JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set."

Tags: windows, hadoop, java-home

I'm trying to get Hadoop running 'Local Mode' on my Windows machine. I've been using this guide: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/single_node_setup.html

When I run the command: bin/hadoop, I get the following error message:

> Error: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set.  Please update
>   C:...\hadoop-2.7.1\conf\hadoop-env.cmd

Inside `hadoop-env.cmd`, I have the line:
`set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%`

When I type `echo %JAVA_HOME%` at the command line I get:
`C:\Java\jdk1.0.8_51`

Even if I change the line in `hadoop-env.cmd` to:
`set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.0.8_51`
I get the same error...

How could it be that my `JAVA_HOME` is incorrectly set?

Comment: Try setting JAVA_HOME environment variable at a system level not just your shell (assuming you just set it in the shell). If not then run 'Java -version' at a command prompt.

Comment: Thanks for your response Heath. I have set it at a system level. I have a system variable JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.0.8_51 ; and I have C:\Java\jdk1.0.8_51\bin in my PATH user variable. Typing in Java -version at the prompt returns -> "java version 1.8.0_51..."

Comment: Does opening a new prompt and running hadoop work now

Comment: No. Sorry, I should have included a mention of that in my previous comment.

Comment: check this to resolve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/70630733/6236959

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If your JAVA_HOME path contains spaces, you must use the [Windows 8.3 Pathname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)

Comment: is right! Thanks for saving my day.
Just want to make it more detial, if you use the default setting while installing JAVA, you will have to set the JAVA_HOME to something like "C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_xxx". (Don't forget to replace xxx to your actual jdk update id.)

Comment: Right! I also encountered the JAVA_HOME problem. But then, I got another error message "Error: Could not find or load main Trung"

Comment: @Duong edit set HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=%USERNAME% to HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=username(without space) in hadoop-env.cmd file

Answer (score 32):

like the other answers, your java environment path must not contain space. 
The solution is as follows:

1. In the cmd line, charge the directory that contain the jdk (in my case C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73).
2. execute the following line "for %I in (.) do echo %~sI" to display the short name of your installed jdk (in my case C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_7)
3. in the file "hadoop-env.cmd", change the line "JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%" with "JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_7".
4. run again the file "hadoop-env.cmd" and it will work correctly.

Answer (score 21):

```
 set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\
```

Above configuration was throwing same error as yours. I updated above with below in hadoop-env.cmd which is infact [SFN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\
```

This allowed me to change/have different java version than that of system.

Answer (score 3):

Try to place the java path in double-coats. Example:

```
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1"
```

It should work fine.

Comment: That's not working. `spark-shell` for example will throw error.

Answer (score 2):

Use
"%JAVA_HOME%" in conf\hadoop-env.cmd

Answer (score 1):

if your java environment path contains space, such as "C:\Program Files\java\xxxxx" , the word 《Program Files》 contains a space, so CMD can't identificate

this is the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Try removing @ from @rem in hadoop-env.cmd and set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%

```
rem The java implementation to use.  Required.
```

set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%

Then try running hdfs namenode -format

This solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

[image: error vs fixed]

**Explanation :** `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11`
If you set this path to *"System Environment Variables"*, Java will work normally on your machine.  (*jdk11* can be different in your case)

But when it comes to Hadoop, it looks like this in *"hadoop-env.cmd"* file :

`set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11` : *"hadoop-env.cmd"* file will ignore path after space :
`C:\Program` + `Files\Java\jdk-11` will be treated as two different things.

**Solution :**

**step 1 :** Copy *"Java"* folder from `C:\Program Files\Java`
and paste it in *"C:"* directory,
it will look like this : *"C:\Java"*

**step 2 :** Now edit *"hadoop-env.cmd"* file : `set JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk-11`

**step 3 :** make sure to give same path in *"System Environment Variables"* :

*"JAVA_HOME"* : `C:\Java\jdk-11` & *"path"* : `C:\Java\jdk-11\bin`

Restart your IDE.

- **Alternate Solution :** If you want to go with same path with spaces, then you should read about it here :
  [using-spaces-in-windows-cmd-file-or-batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851012/set-a-path-variable-with-spaces-in-the-path-in-a-windows-cmd-file-or-batch-file)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In `hadoop-env.cmd` I changed %JAVA_HOME% to `"C:\Program Files\openjdk-17_windows-x64_bin\jdk-17"` with double quotation. It worked for me

set `JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\openjdk-17_windows-x64_bin\jdk-17"`

[image]

Answer (score -2):

in hadoop-config.xml， the logic is

if not exist %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe (
  echo Error: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set.
  echo        Please update %HADOOP_HOME%\conf\hadoop-env.cmd
  goto :eof
)

if your java environment path contains *space*, such as "C:\Program Files\java\xxxxx"  , the word 《Program Files》 contains a *space*,  so CMD can't identificate

SO your can change the path instead.