# JAVA_HOME is set incorrectly -- Hadoop on Windows 10

Tags: java, hadoop, environment-variables

**Context:** I am trying to install Hadoop on my Windows 10 machine. I've followed the directions [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7Qpnmi0Q-s) and I'm having a lot of difficulty completing the process. I keep raising the following error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.
> Error: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set.
> Please update C:\Users\eric\Downloads\hadoop-3.1.4.tar\hadoop-3.1.4\hadoop-3.1.4\etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.cmd'-Dhadoop.security.logger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

When I check the version of Java I get the following, so I know for sure Java has been installed.

```
C:\Java\bin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
```

I gather from the above error there's an issue with the path in the environment variable I've set for JAVA_HOME. I'm really unclear why the error refers to that directory in the message because when I `echo %JAVA_HOME%` at terminal I get `C:\Java\bin` as the environment variable path (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621032/hadoop-on-windows-error-java-home-is-incorrectly-set/51859497)).

**Question:** I'm guessing the jdk file cant be found/is lost or something else. How do I resolve these issues? And where can I find this JDK file (the `jdkl.8.0_241` file shown @11:55 in the video) because it doesnt appear to be in the bin folder of the JDK download? Please help. This question is NOT a duplicate, because the issue seems to be more closely related to the JDK file.

Comment: Please don't include images of text, include the text directly (your command prompt).

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` should point to `C:\Java`, not `C:\Java\bin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JAVA_HOME** should be point to the root directory of a Java JDK and should be specified in the **environment variable**s. After setting this value a restart of the terminal/application/console/IDE/command-prompt is required to make the new value active.

If you simple give: `java --version` it use the first java.exe version found on your **PATH**. **JAVA_HOME** and the **PATH** java version don't have any relation with each other.

**JAVA_HOME** can be specified for example to: "c:/java/jdk9" and your path includes "c:/java/jdk8/bin". In this situation `java --version` will give you `1.8.x.x`.

**JAVA_HOME** is used by processes that forks to a new subproces and then used that **JAVA_HOME** value.

In your situation there is probably only a spacer missing in/after the call to hadoop-env.cmd ?? (not clear with the current info)