# Hadoop error on Windows : java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: hadoop

I am new to Hadoop and trying to execute my first mapreduce job of wordcount.
However, whenever I am trying to do it, I am getting the below error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.nativeCompute
ChunkedSumsByteArray(II[BI[BIILjava/lang/String;JZ)V
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.nativeComputeChunkedSumsByteArray(
Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCrc32.calculateChunkedSumsByteArray(Nati
veCrc32.java:86)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DataChecksum.calculateChunkedSums(DataChecksum
.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.writeChecksumChunks(FSOutputSumme
r.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.flushBuffer(FSOutputSummer.java:1
63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.flushBuffer(FSOutputSummer.java:1
44)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.close(DFSOutputStream.java:221
7)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOut
putStream.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java
:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.closeStream(IOUtils.java:254)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(IOUtils.java:112)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:366)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:338)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:190
5)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:187
3)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(FileSystem.java:183
8)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.copyJar(JobResourceUp
loader.java:246)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.uploadFiles(JobResour
ceUploader.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSub
mitter.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitt
er.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1297)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1294)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInforma
tion.java:1656)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1294)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1315)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(Progra
mDriver.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Also, when I do

hadoop checknative -a

it shows me following details:

```
Native library checking:
hadoop:  true C:\hadoop-2.6.1\bin\hadoop.dll
zlib:    false
snappy:  false
lz4:     true revision:43
bzip2:   false
openssl: false org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsOpenssl()Z
winutils: true C:\hadoop-2.6.1\bin\winutils.exe
15/10/19 15:18:24 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Is there any way I can resolve this issue ?

Comment: Please check if this link helps you : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6974

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had same problem. after removing `hadoop.dll` from the `system32` directory and setting the `HADOOP_HOME` environment variable it worked.

Alternatively use can add a jvm argument like `-Djava.library.path=<hadoop home>/lib/native`.

Comment: Having hadoop.dll and winutils.exe in HADOOP_HOME\bin\ didn't help in my case. However, adding that jvm argument does help.
Thanks

Comment: @Jaigates
Iam a newbie to Hadoop. Could you please tell me where should I paste this command.
-Djava.library.path=<hadoop home>/lib/native

Answer (score 11):

I had this error too and I resolved this error:

1. You access link https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils
2. Download file "winutils.exe" and "hadoop.dll" **with version which you use**
3. Copy 2 file to HADOOP_HOME\bin.

It's Ok for me.
**Note: if 2 file "winutils.exe" and "hadoop.dll" not right with hadoop version which you use, it isn't OK**

Comment: Worked for me as well ! Thanks

Comment: @Duc how do i check if the hadoop.dll and winutils.exe are compatible

Comment: @Duc Iam using Hadoop-3.0.0. Inspite of copying the files to HADOOP-HOME/bin didnt help me. Can you please help

Comment: @NeeleshkumarS Request you to please help

Comment: @JonAndrews, I did used Hadoop 2.8 instead of Hadoop 3

Comment: @NeeleshkumarS Iam able to start the daemons from Windows command prompt. But Iam unable to start the same from Cngwin command prompt

Answer (score 1):

check whether same C:\hadoop-2.6.1\bin\hadoop.dll file is used by the java process while you get this error.
use process explorer to find.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spark2.4.6

I downloaded hadoop-2.9.0 from https://archive.apache.org/dist/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.9.0/

Then during execution of my code where I am also writing the output to an external file,

I used **-Djava.library.path=<path to extracted hadoop-2.9.0>/lib/native**
as VM arguments.

That's it & it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Check your java version. If java is 32bits version, you need uninstall and re-install with 64 bits version for hadoop.

Check command:

java -d32 -version;

java -d64 -version;(no error, if 64 version)