# -Dhadoop.security.logger' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, hadoop

I've installed Hadoop 2.8.0 in Windows 7, following the instllation instructions in  [github](https://github.com/MuhammadBilalYar/Hadoop-On-Window/wiki/Step-by-step-Hadoop-2.8.0-installation-on-Window-10), I set JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_HOME Environment variables correctly, and configured the *core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, hadoop-env.cmd* files as required in the document, my path is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbHGK.png)

But after all this is done, I am getting the following error in console fter running **hdfs namenode –format** command

The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set.
       Please update C:\Hadoop-2.8.0\hadoop-2.8.0\etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.cmd
'-Dhadoop.security.logger' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

Comment: check this answer to resolve this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70630733/6236959

Answer (score 2):

Can you set the JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.cmd as

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77"
```

java path is different for each system depending upon 32bit & 64bit. Please choose correct javapath and add quotes.

Answer (score 2):

If your Jdk folder like C:/Program Files/Java/Jdk_1.8_261
file path contain space so you should move your jdk to the folder that folder name does not contain spaces

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your path is between quotation marks
i had the same problem cause i forget the to close the quotation mark.

Comment: please tell which path you are talking about. It will be helpful.

Comment: JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77"

Answer (score 0):

Also can try below way:

Sometimes even we set the right path in hadoop-env.cmd still returns the same error.

so we have to follow below steps:

1. open cmd (command prompt) as a administrator.
2. create symbolic link with your java path (ex: c:\program\java\jdk1.8)
3. in your cmd: $mklink /D \java_home "C:\Program\Java\jdk1.8" (Note: after \D please insert space)
4. now instead of entire path (c:\program\java\jdk1.8) we can use symbolic link
5. open hadoop-env.cmd (edit) and set JAVA_HOME = \java_home
6. Finally save and close the file
7. now again try syntax : $hdfs namenode -format