# Getting Error when trying to run startup.bat of Apache-Tomcat : JRE_HOME variable is not defined correctly

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

When I am trying to start Apache Tomcat Server through cmd prompt using `startup.bat`, I am getting this error:

```
JRE_HOME variable is not defined correctly. The environment variable is needed to Run this program
```

I have Defined the following Environment Variables Path as-

```
CATALINA_HOME - C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.78;

JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65;

JRE_Home - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77;

CLASSPATH - C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65;\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_77\bin;C:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.78\lib;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate and the original question is an easy find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438160/java-home-variable

Answer (score 0):

You can check the validity of the paths by

> echo %JAVA_HOME%
>
> echo %JRE_HOME%
>
> echo %CATALINA_HOME%

Try to set CLASSPATH as

> CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JRE_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\lib