# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory - ionic

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I just got a new computer which didn't have java or android sdk installed, I added both today, but the first time I made a mistake and downloaded `java 10` and set that as the `JAVA_HOME` but since then I downloaded `java jdk 1.8` and made that the `JAVA_HOME` but I'm still getting an error:

I'm doing - `ionic cordova run android --device` with the error report saying:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin
studio

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
(node:56548) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

So it's saying I don't have the correct directory, but I'm pretty sure I do:

[image]

and here is my `environment variables`:

[image]

However... when I do `java -version` it returns:

```
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

Not sure if that's normal...

What should I do? I think all the info should be correct.. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The `JAVA_HOME` *contains* the `bin` folder. You need `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch should the `Path` have the `bin`?

Comment: Might need to remove spaces https://stackoverflow.com/a/11953150/2308683

Comment: PATH should have the bin. JAVA_HOME should not

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that worked. I can mark you as the answer if you create one...